# How to get twitter username, full name using tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I managed to get tweet.it and text . But  I struggle to get the user and place items from user_fields.

```
query="covid-is:retweet"
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query, 
                          expansions='entities.mentions.username',
                          user_fields=['username'],
                          tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], 
                          max_results=10).flatten(limit=10)
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.user.screen_name)
```

How can I get username or full name using tweepy.paginator?
Advance thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _the user_: The author of the tweet, or users that might be mentioned in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for you

```
import tweepy

bearer_token ="********** your token *********"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)
query="covid"
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                                expansions='entities.mentions.username',
                                query=query,
                                 max_results=10).flatten(limit=10):
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    if tweet.entities['mentions'] is not None:
        print(tweet.entities['mentions'][0])
        print(tweet.entities['mentions'][0]['username']) #username
        print('https://twitter.com/{0}/status/{1}'.format(tweet.entities['mentions'][0]['username'], tweet.id))
```

Results

```
$ python get-user-name.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 13, 'username': 'H_Scott_M', 'id': '1484522689897373699'}
H_Scott_M
https://twitter.com/H_Scott_M/status/1617343377724276738
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 15, 'username': 'ElectionWiz', 'id': '1290635110149169152'}
ElectionWiz
https://twitter.com/ElectionWiz/status/1617343376894087170
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 17, 'username': 'AmeliaNGibson', 'id': '192424439'}
AmeliaNGibson
https://twitter.com/AmeliaNGibson/status/1617343376415948802
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 18, 'username': 'CamargoDireita', 'id': '1489189886670381056'}
CamargoDireita
https://twitter.com/CamargoDireita/status/1617343375421898752
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 14, 'username': 'ClayTravis', 'id': '50772918'}
ClayTravis
https://twitter.com/ClayTravis/status/1617343375166050304
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 14, 'username': 'RWMaloneMD', 'id': '39844876'}
RWMaloneMD
https://twitter.com/RWMaloneMD/status/1617343374272651266
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 19, 'username': 'KanekoaTheGreat', 'id': '1085225533623783424'}
KanekoaTheGreat
https://twitter.com/KanekoaTheGreat/status/1617343373479710720
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 19, 'username': 'claudiovarella1', 'id': '88716759'}
claudiovarella1
https://twitter.com/claudiovarella1/status/1617343373404418048
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 17, 'username': 'DashDobrofsky', 'id': '1520612280643162112'}
DashDobrofsky
https://twitter.com/DashDobrofsky/status/1617343373341491203
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'start': 3, 'end': 15, 'username': 'VigilantFox', 'id': '191871143'}
VigilantFox
https://twitter.com/VigilantFox/status/1617343373257637889
```

This V2 API help to access username in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent)

V2 API equal with `tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets)`

```
GET /2/tweets/search/recent
```

[image]

The user name location test by Postman
How to use `entities['mentions'][0]['username']` in Body of Response.

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate , It's working . But it's stopping each time

if tweet.entities['mentions'] is not None:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: some tweet has no values for entities like a my Postman's first tweet in Body. The id is 1617333827168358402. So you needs to checking not None as same as my code `if tweet.entities['mentions'] is not None:`.